# How to set checked property in vba (format or control toolbox)

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I'm trying to change the value of my checkbox to true based on a another cell's value

```
if range("A1").value = "green" then
Checkbox1.value= true

end if
```

How to I change the value property to true for multiple checkbox at the same time

For some reason the code that i've tried doesn't do anything at all. 
P.S. I'm using format checkboxes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will change all Checkboxes

```
Sub Changeboxes()

    Dim cb As CheckBox

    If Sheet1.Range("a1").Value = "green" Then
        For Each cb In Sheet1.CheckBoxes
            cb.Value = True
        Next cb
    End If

End Sub
```

If you need to specify particular checkboxes, then

```
Sub ChangeSomeCbs()

    If Sheet1.Range("a1").Value = "green" Then
        Sheet1.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value = True
        Sheet1.CheckBoxes("Check Box 2").Value = False
        Sheet1.CheckBoxes("Check Box 3").Value = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Checkbox and Checkboxes are hidden properties.  You won't get intellisense, but they work.

Comment: I'm trying to specify the checkboxes on my form that I want to put a check mark in. For example for checkbox1 , I want the user to see it ticked.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
If range("O26").Value = "green" Then
    CheckBox1.Value = True
    CheckBox2.Value = True
End If
```

If you are in design mode this will not work.

Comment: The code gives me an object required error(424) I've also tried to put an And after my first Checkbox.value = true statement but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This code is true for Office365:

```
If range("O26").Value = "green" Then
    CheckBox1 = True
    CheckBox2 = True
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

For ActiveX checkboxes, use this format:

`ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Checkbox1").Object.Value = True`